# How to access the value of a textfield and store in a variable when a button is clicked

Tags: extjs, extjs4

This is part of the code. I have a `Window`, and a `Form` in it. There's a `text field` and a `button`.  I need to get the Value of the `textfield` and save it to a `var` when the user clicks on the `button`.

Code:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyV', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    alias: 'widget.myV',

    id: 'myvid',

    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;

        Ext.applyIf(me, {
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'form',
                    x: 15,
                    y: 40,
                    frame: true,
                    height: 420,
                    id: 'f11',
                    layout: {
                        type: 'absolute'
                    },
 
                        },
                                                 {
                            xtype: 'textareafield',
                            x: 150,
                            y: 185,
                            id: 'name',
                            width: 320,
                            fieldLabel: 'Name'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'button',
                            x: 100,
                            y: 150,
                           
                            text: 'Send',
                            listeners: {
                                click: {
                                    fn: me.onClickButton,
                                    scope: me
                                }
                            }
                        },
                                            ]
                }
            ],
…..
     
        });
```

The action, WHen the user clicks on the button; The following is my code

```
onClickButton: function(button, e, options) {

        var nameOfPerson    = this.up('form').down('#myvid > #f11 > #name');
```

Can someone help me to get the value the user typed in the `textfield` and save it to the variable `nameOfPerson`. ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Ext.define('Foo', {
    extend : 'Ext.window.Window',
    alias : 'widget.myV',

    id : 'myvid',

    initComponent : function() {
        var me = this;

        Ext.applyIf(me, {
            items : [{
                xtype : 'textareafield',
                width : 320,
                fieldLabel : 'Name',
                itemId: 'name'
            }, {
                xtype : 'button',
                text : 'Send',
                listeners : {
                    scope : me,
                    click : me.onClickButton
                }
            }]
        });
        this.callParent();
    },

    onClickButton: function(){
        var name = this.down('#name').getValue();
        console.log(name);
    }
}); 

Ext.onReady(function(){
    new Foo({
        autoShow: true
    });
});
```

Comment: what about Ext.getCmp('name').getValue();

Comment: What about it? It's basically the same as using a global variable, not really a good idea.

Comment: When i used it like that it prints undefined. What does this mean ?

Comment: The component doesn't have an id, so it can't find it. itemId is local to the container. All of this information is in the docs.